# Clicking a custom UITableView section header is invoking didSelectRow: on first row of the section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom `viewForHeaderInSection` on a `UITableView` - let's call it `HeaderCell` (a simple subclass of `UITableViewCell`) that has the weirdest behaviour:

- When I click on the *section header*:

  - it triggers the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` with the `indexPath` of the first `UITableViewCell` of that section. Like I was clicking on the cell, but no. I'm clicking on the header.

The thing is, if I replace that custom `HeaderCell` on`viewForHeaderInSection` with a simple `UIView`, that doesn't happen anymore! I've checked for any actions linked on that *xib* and its class, couldn't find any `addTarget:` or any *xib* action.

Other weird factor: it does not happen on the first HeaderCell (section 0) only happens on section >= 1.

#### NOTE: I have a quick-fix for this but it's kind of risky for later support

On `HeaderCell` class, i just need to implement:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    return;
}
```

This a last resort solution. Anyone has detected this behaviour before?

Comment: Seems like you have forgot to return the header height in `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` method. Make sure you are returning correct height for your header.

Comment: Checked it and I'm always returning 50 :/

Comment: You shouldn't be using subclasses of `UITableViewCell` for headers/footers. Use `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` (if you can live with >= iOS6) or simply UIView otherwise.

Comment: Thanks @MikePollard! That's it! I need to support iOS5 so I'll stick with UIView (as I tested before) - will need to re-implement our custom  dequeueReusableHeaderCellWithIdentifier but it's working! Thanks!

Comment: @MikePollard , can you copy your comment to a new answer so I can accept it? Never noticed this was left here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be using subclasses of `UITableViewCell` for headers/footers. Use `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` (if you can live with >= iOS6) or simply `UIView` otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

use `return cell.contentView` instead of `return cell` if you are using  `UITableViewCell` for header/footer

Comment: This is a legacy question targeting iOS 5 and beyond. That time there wasn’t HeaderFooterView. With that available problem was solved

Answer (score 1):

You can do it through setEnableUserInteraction method. Pls refer the code given,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
[cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];


if([indexPath row] == 0)
    [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];



return cell;


}
```

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but I just came across this and another possible way to avoid this if you are using subclasses of UITableViewCell for header, then just return the content view instead of the complete cell in the headerforView function.